# How to toggle mobile desktop view inside a menu in Semantic-UI? Will the responsive to device only works with rows and columns?

Tags: responsive-design, semantic-ui

How to implement **mobile only** or **desktop only** view inside a main menu in Semantic UI? Will the **Responsive to Device** feature only works with rows and columns as stated in [Semantic UI Grid](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html)? Can any one please advice me on how this can be achieved with Semantic UI or should I use javascript to do the same?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: @SurjithSM I have a row with mobile, tablet and computer view in [this snippet](http://codepen.io/vinoth/pen/BgIsj). Can you advice how to implement the same for menu

Comment: Like this http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/ymHin ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but for computer and tablet view we can see a extra padding above menu items due to the following rule .ui.grid > .row { padding: 1rem 0px 0px;}

Comment: You can adjust it manually. See answer below

Answer (score 7):

Add HTML classes to Menu also

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/ymHin)**

HTML

```
<div class="ui inverted menu grid">

  <div class="mobile only row">...</div>
  <div class="tablet only row">...</div>
  <div class="computer only row">...</div>

  </div>
```

For padding issue, Ovrride CSS with the below class

```
.ui.menu.grid>.computer.only.row {
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I agree this can be done in this way but actually I was looking for a implementation to do it natively in semantic-ui.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was looking for this everywhere and to me it would seem to be quite a common request. I don't understand why it's not in the documentation